# How to import fundamentals for stocks by using Quandl package

Tags: r, quandl

I'm trying to import fundamentals for stocks by using Quandl package,I pulled some data by using this line of code:

```
mydata <-Quandl("WIKI/AAPL", collapse="quarterly")
```

However, I don't understend how can I get fundamentals data and not just the price data.
Any Idea how to do that? Also, Is there a way to pull all fundamentals with the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this line of code from the maintainer of the package.There was a typo in the documentation so this is the right syntax:

```
Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COST_OF_REVENUE_TOTAL_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29")
```

Answer (score 2):

On this site you find all the fundamentals:
http://www.quandl.com/c/stocks/aapl. Just click on the figure (quaterly/anualy) and you will be directed to a page with the data. There is an `R` button on the right. Clicking it will give you the `R`-Code.

Example: 
Gross-Profit: http://www.quandl.com/SEC/AAPL_GROSSPROFIT_Q-APPLE-INC-AAPL-Quarterly-Gross-Profit

```
Quandl("SEC/AAPL_GROSSPROFIT_Q", 
       trim_start="2009-06-27", 
       trim_end="2014-03-29")
```

But from my understanding quandl do not have all the fundamental-details like
Bloomberg, Reuters, CapitalIQ.

Comment: Thanks Floo0, do you know how to import the harmonized data into r ?
I tried Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COSTOFREVENUE_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29") but with no luck.

Comment: try it with the "_" as described on WaltS link:
`RAYMOND/MSFT_COST_OF_REVENUE_Q`

Comment: Hey @Floo0,@WaltS,@Ray I tried this line of code: Quandl("RAYMOND/MSFT_COST_OF_REVENUE_Q", trim_start="2009-06-27", trim_end="2014-03-29")
but got: "Requested entity does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

There can be an issue needing to use different SEC codes to obtain comparable data on different companies so Quandl hss recently provided a harmonized set of tags which can be used for some of the more common data types.  In addition to Floo0 references, you might want to check out http://www.quandl.com/help/api-for-stock-data#SEC-Harmonized-Data